# Como deshabilitar campos de un formulario dependiendo que escriba el usuario en un input type php

Tags: php, laravel, formularios

hola me encuentro tratando de deshabilitar un campo de un formulario "personal que atiende" si el usuario escribe un codigo especifico en el input-text "procedimientos" la idea es que se deshabilite si se ingresa dicho codigo he intentado con addeventlistener pero solo es viable con un input typo select y mi input es tipo texto porque se autocompleta con una lista de 8500 codigos de procedimientos entonces por eso no puedo usar esta opcion si alguien conoce un metodo que me pueda servir le agradezco de antemano

//campo de donde saldria el valor para deshabilitar el otro campo

```php
<label><?php echo trans('medical-histories.procedure_code'); ?></label>
<input type="text" data-name="procedure_code_autocompletation" class="form-control procedure-code-autocompletation" autocomplete="off" value="<?php  echo !empty($consultationRipsProcedures) ? $consultationRipsProcedures->procedure_code : ''; ?>">
<input type="hidden" data-name="procedure_code" class="form-control procedure-code">


//campo que desearia deshabilitar si ingreso determinado codigo//
<label><?php echo trans('medical-histories.personal_attention'); ?></label>
<select data-name="personal_attention" id="personal_attention" class="form-control personal-attention">
    <option value=""></option>
<?php foreach (PersonalAttention::getAll() as $personalAttention) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $personalAttention->getValue(); ?>" <?php  echo !empty($consultationRipsProcedures) && $consultationRipsProcedures->personal_attention == $personalAttention->getValue() ? 'selected' : ''; ?> ><?php echo trans('medical-histories.'.$personalAttention->getName(true)); ?></option><?php } ?>
</select>
```

asi esta la parte de javasrcipt

```
<script>
const procedures = document.getElementById('inputprocedures');
const attention = document.getElementById('personal_attention');
const case1 = '735301 - ASISTENCIA DEL PARTO CON O SIN EPISIORRAFIA O PERINEORRAFIA';
const case2 = '735930 - ASISTENCIA DEL PARTO ESPONTÁNEO GEMELAR O MÚLTIPLE';
const case3 = '735931 - ASISTENCIA DEL PARTO INTERVENIDO GEMELAR O MÚLTIPLE';
const case4 = '735980 - OTRA ASISTENCIA MANUAL DEL PARTO ESPONTÁNEO';
if (procedures != case1 || case2 || case3 || case4) {
    procedures.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  attention.disabled = true;
});
}
//codigo sugerido//
procedures.oninput = ev => attention.disabled = procedures.value === '735301 - ASISTENCIA DEL PARTO CON O SIN EPISIORRAFIA O PERINEORRAFIA';
```

necesito que cuando el usuario escriba en el input alguno de esos casos ya que es autocomplete habilite el otro campo de personal que atiende si ingresa otro codigo que este se deshabilite

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.SO], recuerda realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta no es clara, y el código que adjuntas parece no tener ninguna relación o está totalmente incompleto. Hablas de "campos", de "input-text" de "addEventListener" de "select". Pero en ninguna parte del código muestras nada de eso. Revisa [ask]

Comment: usa ajax para validar el campo y recargar la información que requieras, [asi](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)

Comment: @Pipe Cuando en una pregunta no veas el código del que hablan prueba de editarla y es probable, como en este caso, que el código hubiera quedado escondido porque si ponen html al principio de la línea (sin tabulación y sin las tres tildes graves) éste queda escondido. La acabo de editar y he visto que el código si que estaba y lo he puesto para que se vea.

Comment: añade el código que has intentado probar o el que estas usando de js

Comment: @mastergurubuen dato ;)

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que comentas deberás añadir un evento input al propio input y evaluar el contenido conforme se va escribiendo y cuando cumpla la condición (si la cumple) modificas el otro input o select para deshabilitarlo.

```js
const procedures = document.getElementById('inputprocedures');
const attention = document.getElementById('personal_attention');

procedures.oninput = ev => attention.disabled = procedures.value === 'procedures';
```

```html
<label><?php echo trans('medical-histories.procedure_code'); ?></label>
<input type="text" data-name="procedure_code_autocompletation" class="form-control procedure-code-autocompletation" autocomplete="off" value="<?php  echo !empty($consultationRipsProcedures) ? $consultationRipsProcedures->procedure_code : ''; ?>" id="inputprocedures">
<input type="hidden" data-name="procedure_code" class="form-control procedure-code">


//campo que desearia deshabilitar si ingreso determinado codigo//
<label><?php echo trans('medical-histories.personal_attention'); ?></label>
<select data-name="personal_attention" id="personal_attention" class="form-control personal-attention">
    <option value="" selected disabled></option>
    <-- Rellenar con opciones -->
</select>
```

Con esto debería funcionar y hacer lo que comentas.

Comment: hola no entiendo muy bien como implementar tu respuesta ahi agregue mi parte de javascript